# AVFoundation allows to easily spy you?

Tags: ios, camera, avfoundation

I recently discovered this: http://openradar.appspot.com/15880263

Correct me if I'm wrong, but those lines allows a Developer to spy the user without the user even noticing, right?

```
AVCaptureDevice *frontDevice = nil;
for (AVCaptureDevice *device in [AVCaptureDevice devices]) {
    if (device.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront) {
        frontDevice = device;
    }
}
AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:frontDevice error:nil];
AVCaptureMovieFileOutput *output = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];

session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
[session beginConfiguration];
[session addInput:input];
[session addOutput:output];
[session commitConfiguration];
[session startRunning];

// Wait X seconds

NSString *path = [DOCUMENTS_DIRECTORY stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"output.mov"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[output startRecordingToOutputFileURL:url recordingDelegate:self];
```

and boom, I could send that `output.mov` to my own server, for example. This is terrible, unless I'm missing something.......

Comment: Assuming this is possible: There are certainly some privacy risks, but I can see some useful applications of this. Helping recover stolen devices for example.

Comment: Won't iOS ask you to enable the camera/microphone/GPS before allowing your app to access these sort of features?

Comment: @JamesWebster: We're throwing the Baby with the Bath Water here ;-) @H2CO3: Notice how I don't record audio... Neither do I use `CoreLocation` (GPS). No, for Video, that's the problem, iOS doesn't ask anything to the user.

Comment: And besides, you could make an innocuous Vine clone, so the user has a valid reason to allow camera/microphone access.

Comment: I'm usually totally not in favor of a LED but in this case, that LED on the mac telling you the camera is being used is quite convenient. Of course I guess you can bypass it, but if  was at least putting something in the Status Bar, for example (assuming you show it, obviously!)